# setRequestedOrientation(...) blocks the configuration change from sensor

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am trying to change the screen orientation based on the press of button as well as listening to the configuration change from sensor.

My code looks like:

```
private boolean mFullScreen = false;
...

/**
* This method is used by button to toggle orientation
*/
public void toggleFullScreen() {
    mFullScreen = !mFullScreen;
    switchFullScreen();
}

private void switchFullScreen() {
    if (mFullScreen) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    switch (newConfig.orientation) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            break;
        }
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT: {
            getSupportActionBar().show();
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="Activity"
    android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation />
```

At first the configuration change from sensor is detected, but once orientation is toggled from the button, it is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

Only with `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` and `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR` your activity will react on sensor. Setting your screen orientation to portrait or landscape blocks the rotation, it's their main purpose

Comment: Actually I was trying to obtain player like that of youtube, where both sensor and buttons can be used to change the orientation.

Comment: @Samir I'm trying to do the same thing now. Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Is there any update on this? Trying to achieve the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
private void switchFullScreen() {
    if (mFullScreen) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```